# test a plug-in components with monkey -c options but fail : no activities found for category

Tags: android, monkey

I am trying to test plug-in components with monkey.(It is an app A launch by another app B.it has a few functions with activities but have no launcher Activity.)

As this app does not have any app icon because, there is no Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER or Intent.CATEGORY_MONKEY in manifest.xml

The package name is correct. Install or uninstall the application using it is working.

my test code

```
adb shell monkey -p package.name 100
** No activities found to run, monkey aborted.
```

and

```
adb shell monkey -p package.name -c CurMainActivity 100
// Warning: no activities found for category CurMainActivity
** No activities found to run, monkey aborted.
```

checked  CurMainActivity is

```
   public class CurMainActivity extends BaseActivity implements xxxxxxxxxxx {
```

i think it means that there is an Activity.
Also i could make an launcher for the app...but i want to learn about -c option.